# excel vba userform picture change on click

Tags: image, vba, excel, userform

I made a userform with 10 * 4 spaces for pictures("set11", "set12", ...). At the beginning they are empty. When I click on one of the pictures they should be reset by a random picture(function getRandomPath).

The sub "clicked" works if I use a Button(start) to click. If I click a picture nothing happens. When I now click again on the Button(start), the before clicked pictures don't change no more.

Here is the relevant code:

```
Private Sub set11_Click() 
    Call clicked("1", "1") '*doesn't work*
End Sub 

Private Sub set12_Click() 
    Call clicked("1", "2") '*doesn't work*
End Sub 

Private Sub set13_Click() 
    Call clicked("1", "3") '*doesn't work*
End Sub 

Private Sub set14_Click() 
    Call clicked("1", "4") '*doesn't work*
End Sub 

Private Sub clicked(row As String, column As String) 
    Controls("set" & row & column).Picture = LoadPicture(getRandomPfad()) 
End Sub

Private Sub start_Click() 
    Call clearpictures 
    set11.Picture = LoadPicture(getRandomPfad()) '*works*
    Controls("set12").Picture = LoadPicture(getRandomPfad()) '*works*
    Call clicked("1", "3") '*works*
End Sub

Private Function getRandomPfad()
    Dim random As Integer
    random = Int(6 * Rnd + 1)
    Select Case random
        Case Is = 1
            getRandomPfad = "U:\MMpic\Green.jpg"
        Case Is = 2
            getRandomPfad = "U:\MMpic\Blue.jpg"
        Case Is = 3
            getRandomPfad = "U:\MMpic\Yellow.jpg"
        Case Is = 4
            getRandomPfad = "U:\MMpic\Pink.jpg"
        Case Is = 5
            getRandomPfad = "U:\MMpic\Orange.jpg"
        Case Is = 6
            getRandomPfad = "U:\MMpic\Red.jpg"
    End Select
End Function
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: You have different things going on in start_click than all the subs that don't work.  Like the clearpictures call that is happening doesn't get called from the set_click

Comment: Could you post the code for the function `getRandomPfad`

Answer (score 0):

Your code must exist inside the userform.  If the code is within a Module, it will not work.
[image]

Also, ensure you have named the image controls to match the names given in your code: "set11"

[image]

Comment: It is in the UserForm

Comment: Right click on the image control in the design mode and select properties.  Do the names in the code match the name within the properties?

Comment: Tey do. The program runs through the code, only the picture doesn't change.

Comment: Put [Break Points](http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s196/breakpoints.htm) in subs for the image controls.  Then, while the form is open, click on an image control.  Does the code stop on the break point?

Comment: Yes it does stop there. In addition, the picture is added to the object, but it isn't shown in the userform.

Comment: Can you explain, "the picture is added to the object..."  Is there more code?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I should have repainted:

```
Private Sub clicked(row As String, column As String) 
    Controls("set" & row & column).Picture = LoadPicture(getRandomPfad())
    Repaint
End Sub
```

But thank you for your help!